# How can I change the font size differently?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

for example, I want to make 'Hello world' into 'Hello (//bigger than world) world (//smaller than Hello)'
and they are in a one line.

How can I do that?
Can I give their fontsize differently in one Text() widget by TextStyle()?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `RichText` widget like this:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code as you want.

```
  RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: 'world!',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```